# Kubernetes Preview environments

Tags: kubernetes, preview, test-environments

I would like to ask what people use to provision an ephemeral preview environment in AWS EKS for your service under test. Also in addition, I am curious to know how you provision any dependent services (such as Database).

E.g. I am working on a `back-end` service and would like to deploy an isolated ephemeral version of this service packaged from my feature branch, including the database. Furthermore, I would also like copy of a `front-end` service in my isolated environment to test my `back-end`.

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own solution: by wiring together your own CI/CD (Jenkins, CircleCI, BuildKite, Github Actions, etc) solution to trigger building and deploying of a preview environment by tying in to webhooks on your source repository.  This would have to include your building of the modified code, then deploying that code to some staging environments, then of course seeding those environments with some type of data.

There is a bit of nuance to getting this right. You should check out https://ephemeralenvironments.io/ which is a good template of what needs to go in to these environments.

A lot of other folks use services that provide this as a SaaS platform, Shipyard.build, Release, and Velocity.tech are a few of your options.

*Disclaimer: I'm on the Operations team at Shipyard*

Hope this helps!